# Put Microsoft Excel xlsx document

Tags: microsoft

I want display Microsoft Excel xlsx sheet in wordpress. How i can do that? Also it will be looking like excel sheet.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBofs.png

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MarufAlam, welcome. Please take a look at our [FAQ page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) as this question is not really within the scope of what we handle here. That said, I've posted an answer for you that should help. If it works for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet will be using the [Google Document Embedder plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-document-embedder/). It has sketchy support for the new X MS Office files, but will sometimes work. If not, you'll need to re-save the file as the old XLS filetype.